# MInecraft считывание данных с клиента

Tags: python, minecraft

Всем привет! Хотел написать бота на Python для игры Майнкрафт, суть в том чтобы пока блок на который смотрит наш персонаж равняется определённым значениям (например железная руда или угольная руда) он выполнял определённый код (например эмулировал нажатие клавиш, с этим проблем нету). Я застрял на моменте проверки на какой блок он смотрит, я предполагаю что можно считать блок на который смотрит наш персонаж с процесса minecraft.exe но как это сделать и можно ли вообще это сделать я не знаю. Я гуглил, но информации не нашёл, так что буду благодарен кто скинет руководство по этому поводу